# PHP - Issue with get text outside form

Tags: php, forms, text, get

i want to get text (after submit) and echo it in inputtext, but i face a problem.
i want to echo text in inputtext, which is this inputtext outside form, it is fail.
but if inputtext inside a form it is success to get text.

1.inputtext inside form -> success

```
<form id="form1" method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name='search'/>
<?php
$db = mysql_connect($dbHost,$dbUser,$dbPass);
mysql_select_db($dbname,$db);
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM adminklasifier");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $clsfr = $row['klasifier'];
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM adminklasifier");
        echo '<select name="cmake" id="cmake" autofocus width="10" onchange="document.getElementById(\'inputtext\').value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].text">';
        echo '<option value="0">-Pilih Domain Klasifikasi-</option>';
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
            echo '<option ' . ($clsfr==$row['klasifier']) . ' value="'.$row['klasifier'].'"'.(($_POST['cmake'] == $row['klasifier']) ? 'selected=selected' : NULL).'>'.$row['klasifier'].'</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
}
?>
<input type="submit" id='button' name='button' value="Cari"></input>
<input type="text" name="inputtext" id="inputtext" value="<?php echo $_POST['inputtext'];?>" />
</form>
```

2.inputtext outside form -> fail

```
 <form id="form1" method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name='search'/>
    <?php
    $db = mysql_connect($dbHost,$dbUser,$dbPass);
    mysql_select_db($dbname,$db);
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM adminklasifier");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $clsfr = $row['klasifier'];
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM adminklasifier");
            echo '<select name="cmake" id="cmake" autofocus width="10" onchange="document.getElementById(\'inputtext\').value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].text">';
            echo '<option value="0">-Pilih Domain Klasifikasi-</option>';
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
                echo '<option ' . ($clsfr==$row['klasifier']) . ' value="'.$row['klasifier'].'"'.(($_POST['cmake'] == $row['klasifier']) ? 'selected=selected' : NULL).'>'.$row['klasifier'].'</option>';
        }
        echo '</select>';
    }
    ?>
    <input type="submit" id='button' name='button' value="Cari"></input>
    </form>
    <input type="text" name="inputtext" id="inputtext" value="<?php echo $_POST['inputtext'];?>" />
```

Can you help to analyze this problem?
And i want to get text and echo it in inputtext, but inputtext outside form (like case no.2), will you fix my code?
Thanks for helping me.

Comment: An input tag needs to be inside a `<form>` tag (at least up until HTML5, anyway). If you want it to be submitted as part of the form, you need to put it inside the `<form>` tags.

Comment: why do you need an `<input>` outside the form tags?

Comment: hemm, sean and andrewsi, just try to catch text and put it in the input

Answer (score 1):

```
<input> fields must exist inside a <form> tag
```

If you just want to display data outside the form put it in a html tag

of  like this.

```
<p><?php echo $_POST['inputtext'];?></p>
```

Comment: According to the w3 standards - http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#form-controls an input outside form tags is vaild - from the end of 17.2.1 `The elements used to create controls generally appear inside a FORM element, but may also appear outside of a FORM element declaration when they are used to build user interfaces.`

Comment: @Sean Yes but if you dont want to actually use it as an input dont, it only adds to confusion when you come back to look at the code some time later. I admit I assumed that there was not input requirements for thsi field

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the generated HTML source code? Your code should show up even though the element is outside of the form. However, it is not the best practice to have it outside the form